# How to count the space used to hold the input on the call stack for recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Suppose I have a function

```
public void dfs(int[] a, int[] b, int count){
     if(count == 0) return;
     dfs(a, b, count-1);
     return;
}
```

I want to calculate the space complexity of dfs. The depth of the call stack would be count. Then on each call stack I need to store a copy of a, and b. Based on this reasoning, I would tend to conclude that the space complexity is: O((a.length + b.length) * count). However, I think when Java passes an object to a function, it just passes a copy of the address of a, b to a given function. Thus, I think each call stack does not need O(a.length + b.length) space to hold the input. It only needs the space to store the addresses of a and b which should be constant. Is this correct?

Comment: A pointer to the first array element would be passed, so ```O((a.length + b.length) * count)``` would be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement is correct. No copies of the input arrays are made, so the only additional space needed is linear in the depth of the stack: O(count).